# How to configure Fluentd forwarder to stream logs to loadbalancer connected to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, fluentd, amazon-elb

I currently have launched an EC2 instance with Fluentd installed, and using `in_forward` Input plugin to receive logs from the other services. On the other side, the service will be sending logs to the EC2 instance `out_forward` Buffered Output plugin. For better security,I would like to create a loadbalancer in front of the EC2 instance, how should I change the fluentd.conf?Should I just replace the EC2 instance IP with the loadbalancer's one, or other config is needed?Thanks!

My Current fluentd.conf

Forwarder

```
# fluentd/conf/fluent.conf
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
    @type forward
    transport tls
    tls_cert_path /path/to/fluentd.crt
    tls_verify hostname false
    <server>
        host <EC2_instane_IP>
        port 24224
    </server>
</match>
```

Receiver

```
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind "0.0.0.0"
    <transport tls>
      cert_path "/path/to/fluentd.crt"
      private_key_path "/path/to/fluentd.key"
    </transport>
  </source>
  <match *.**>
    type elasticsearch
    host "localhost"
    port 9200
    index_name "app"
    type_name "log"
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key "@log_name"
    logstash_format true
    flush_interval 10s
    <buffer>
      flush_interval 10s
    </buffer>
  </match>
```

Comment: You can configure an LB and your EC2 instance will be its backend. `fluentd` will send logs to LB; and, LB will forward logs to its backend. So, you need to configure the LB's IP address and port in `fluentd`'s configuration and the rest should work if the infrastructure has been configured properly.

Answer (score 2):

@jenny your configs shouldn't change much. The forwarders will use <Load_Balancer_DNS_Name> for host. You will need to configure a load balancer in AWS w/ a listener on 24224 that forwards traffic to a target group consisting of your ec2 instance(s).